# Invalid floating point operation occurred SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working to get the distance using SQL function but i am getting getting the following error

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

Here is my function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MeasureDistance] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @lat1 as float,
    @long1 as float,
    @lat2 as float,
    @long2 as float
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
declare @DegToRad as float
declare @Ans as float
declare @Miles as float

set @DegToRad = 57.29577951
set @Ans = 0
set @Miles = 0

if @lat1 is null or @lat1 = 0 or @long1 is null or @long1 = 0 or @lat2 is
null or @lat2 = 0 or @long2 is null or @long2 = 0
begin
return @Miles 
end
set @Ans = SIN(@lat1 / @DegToRad) * SIN(@lat2 / @DegToRad) + COS(@lat1 / @DegToRad ) * COS( @lat2 / @DegToRad ) * COS(ABS(@long2 - @long1 )/@DegToRad)
set @Miles = 3959 * ATAN(SQRT(1 - SQUARE(@Ans)) / @Ans)
set @Miles = CEILING(@Miles) * 1.609344
return @Miles
END
```

When i send 25.2048,55.2708 Lat and Long i am getting the following error.

Comment: SQL Server has spatial types and functions. You should use [geometry.STDistance()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stdistance-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) or [geography.STDistance()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  `real` instead of float

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MeasureDistance] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @lat1 as real,
    @long1 as real,
    @lat2 as real,
    @long2 as real
)
RETURNS real
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
declare @DegToRad as real
declare @Ans as real
declare @Miles as real

set @DegToRad = 57.29577951
set @Ans = 0
set @Miles = 0

if @lat1 is null or @lat1 = 0 or @long1 is null or @long1 = 0 or @lat2 is
null or @lat2 = 0 or @long2 is null or @long2 = 0
begin
return @Miles 
end
set @Ans = SIN(@lat1 / @DegToRad) * SIN(@lat2 / @DegToRad) + COS(@lat1 / @DegToRad ) * COS( @lat2 / @DegToRad ) * COS(ABS(@long2 - @long1 )/@DegToRad)
set @Miles = 3959 * ATAN(SQRT(1 - SQUARE(@Ans)) / @Ans)
set @Miles = CEILING(@Miles) * 1.609344
return @Miles
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using float datatype, you can use numeric, money but float should be completely avoided because of a rounding issue.  Real, float, and double data types in SQL represent approximate numeric values. In your case you should use numeric